# QTP Run Error:Type does not match

Tags: vbscript, qtp

Here is a sniplet of the QTP code :

```
Call CreateResultFile("E:\2012MX\Result\test_d\")
```

And the error is:

> The test run cannot continue due to unrecoverable error. Type does not
>   match：'CreateResultFile'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is the error you would get if `CreateResultFile` wasn't defined, are you sure such a function exists?

Answer (score 0):

1) Somewhere `CreateResultFile` is declared as an variable, array or as an class/object. It cann't be called, but has to be used as an object of that type.

-or-

2) You did not use `Option Explicit` in your script (An Unforgivable Sin: each time you run a script without option explicit, somewhere on Earth a puppy dies). QTP sees undefined functions automagically as undeclared variables and complains with "`Type mismatch`" as explained in 1.
It could be you did not associate the library (vbs or qfl file) with the CreateResultFile function as a resource to the action you are working in.